# Cannot stop array from overflowing in Caesar algorithm

Tags: c, cs50

I have almost finished my code, but ran into the following problem. The code, luckily, works, but when I write as input `ZQ`, with a key of `1`, it gives me the next character of the ASCII chart. Is there a way to stop it from overflowing? If it reaches `Z`, I'd like to go back to the first index character, which would be the `A`. Additionally, it seems to work better when I get rid of the `% 26` in line 39, even though I need to use the formula `ci = (pi + k) % 26`. It gives me no characters as an output otherwise. Thanks!

If a character is uppercase, it should remain uppercase, vice versa with lowercase.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int k = 0;
    string key = argv[1];
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < strlen(key); k++)
        {
            if (!isdigit(key[k]))
            {
                printf("\nUsage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nUsage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
 
    string plaintext = get_string("\nplaintext: ");

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {   
        char c = plaintext[i];
        int keycode = atoi(key);
        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            printf("%c", (c + keycode) % 26);
        }
        else if (isspace(c) || isdigit(c) || ispunct(c))
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In which range are the ASCII code for chars A to Z?(I give away the answer: it's 65 to 90. In which range is `x % 26` for any value of `x`?. In which range is the value of `(c + keycode) % 26` for any values of `c` and `keycode`? If you can answer these three questions, you know what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Rather than iterating over `key` and following up with `atoi`, just use `strtol`.

Answer (score 1):

The number values for letters are offset from the values for the Cæsar cipher, depending on what case it is. You must transform them into numbers in the range of (0, 25), [do the operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), and inverse transform the result back into the case selected. These transformations are fairly simple, *eg* for lower-case letters, `F(c) = c - 'a'`.

Comment: I'm not sure if _"non-linear/linear"_ are the right terms here.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited that to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is correct to handle wrapping from `Z` to `A`, but you must first convert letters to their index value in the alphabet. For the ASCII character set, this conversion is a simple subtraction but must be performed separately for uppercase (`c = 'A'`) and lowercase letters (`c - 'a'`).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int k = 0;
    string key = argv[1];
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        for (k = 0; key[k] != '\0'; k++)
        {
            if (!isdigit((unsigned char)key[k]))
            {
                printf("\nUsage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nUsage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
 
    string plaintext = get_string("\nplaintext: ");
    int keycode = atoi(key);

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0; plaintext[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {   
        char c = plaintext[i];
        if (isupper((unsigned char)c))
        {
            printf("%c", 'A' + (c - 'A' + keycode) % 26);
        }
        else if (islower((unsigned char)c))
        {
            printf("%c", 'a' + (c - 'a' + keycode) % 26);
        }
        else // leave other characters unchanged
        {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```